Vertically center inline flex unordered list beside list with larger text
I'm trying to vertically align this navbar:


.site-title {
  font-size: 26pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-title:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
}

/* added by Editor for demonstration reasons */
nav {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/" class="site-title">Title</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/posts/">Posts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>



However, I'm having trouble getting it centered with the larger title. The list on the right is pushed to the top and I can't figure out a way to center it without setting the padding. Is there a way to do it without setting the padding? I can do it, but I'd like a cleaner way if possible.

Since you're already using Flexbox, you can simply add align-items: center to the nav element:


.site-title {
  font-size: 26pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-title:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    li {
      display: inline-flex;
    }
  }
}

/* added by Editor for demonstration reasons */
nav {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/" class="site-title">Title</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/posts/">Posts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>



